# How can I add a IsMouseOverProperty to a style

Tags: wpf

Here I have customized my button as a circle. But property inside the triggers are not working. I want to set the background to red if `IsEnabled` property is false and `IsMouseOver` property is true.

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid >
                    <Ellipse Stroke="#003878"
                 StrokeThickness="2" >
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                  Color="#003878" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="#003878" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                  Color="#003878" />
                                <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Use [MultiTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @3615 `IsMouseOver` will not fire to _true_ while button is disabled.

Comment: @Sam Roger that, simple multitrigger will not work. Wasn't paying attention to trigger property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background colours set by your triggers are being ignored because you have changed your control's template. It is no longer a standard button with a "background" - instead you are drawing an ellipse with its own set of attributes.

What you need are triggers that will change the ellipse's Fill colour, something like this:-

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Place this XAML inside the `<ControlTemplate>` element, and get rid of your existing `<Style.Triggers>` section.

Note also the `TargetName` attribute in the above XAML, so the setter knows which control inside the template to target. You'll therefore have to add a name to your ellipse like this:-

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Stroke=.... >
```

(My example only changes the ellipse's fill, so you'll probably want to add further triggers to change the stroke colour to red, using the same approach).

Comment: Sorry.I can't mark it as answer since my reputation is less than 15.